# Spring integration setting content type as 'text/xml' for int:http inbound gateway

Tags: spring, integration, spring-integration

Our client is sending a http post request at our int:http inbound gateway which has the following signature:-

```
<int:channel id="http-Input-channel"/>
<int:channel id="http-Output-channnel"/>

<int-http:inbound-gateway id="HttpInboundGateway" 
                          supported-methods="POST,GET"
                          request-payload-type="java.lang.String"
                          request-channel="http-Input-channel"
                          reply-channel="http-Output-channnel" 
                          path="/Response.do"
                          mapped-request-headers="*"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="http-Input-channel" ref="ResponseHandler" output-channel="http-Output-channnel" method="handleMessage"/>
</beans>
```

thus,i am receiving the message via the int:inbound gateway in the service activator's(which is the ResponseHandler bean) method handleMessage() as follows:

public Message handleMessage(Message message) {}

the message contains the results and having the base64 string of the pdf.
when i am debugging i found that the message comes as in the encoded form and content type as 'content-type => application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.
In order to get the actual payload i have to decode that which causes the '+' in the format sent by the client to replace with the space in the whole XML.
if i replace all the spaces with the '+' sign again all works well.i can see the correct format for the whole base64 string of pdf and it opens.

However this is not the actual fix.as client is not sending us the content-type => application/x-www-form-urlencoded in the headers. they are sending that as the content-type => 'text/xml'.

my question is why the int:http inbound gateway changes the content type and encoded the result XML.can we change content type to 'text/xml' of the int http inbound gateway in its configuration before it actually hits the service activator and start processing the XML.
i tired using the message converters but it just duplicates the content type and give preference the application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

can you please suggest what should be used along with the int:http inbound gateway in order to get the result XML having the text/xml as the content type and result XML not in the encoded form.i think changing the content type will solve the problem.but how??

Thanks
dev